# How to check if the Sharepoint site is on Sharepoint online (or On premises).?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Is there any way to check whether the SharePoint site is on SharePoint Online (or On premises).

Can we do that using URL?
I need to write a PowerShell script to check is the site is on SO, but no idea what condition to check.

Found this article https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/01/13/can-can-you-check-the-version-of-a-sharepoint-online-or-how-can-you-know-that-your-sharepoint-online-moved-to-2013/ but not much of help.

thanks
Paru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find that the office 365 links should have a hostname ending in sharepoint.com.

Comment: Okay I will try to use this condition, thank you so much

Comment: i have written the powershell script and it is working fine :)